# How does python determine the PID seemingly without normal system calls in Linux?

Tags: python, linux, system-calls, strace, vdso

When running the following command

```
strace -f python3 -c 'import os; print(os.getpid())'
```

I noticed that strace does not catch the call to the `getpid`(2) system call. I first considered that this was due to glibc caching the pid, but there shouldn't be a pid for libc to cache without at least a single real system call. Then I considered that maybe vdso was the culprit, but running a C program that makes this system call through libc shows a `getpid` call when straced. I finally gave up and looked up the source of the `os.getpid` python module, which apparently seems to be defined in `Modules/posixmodule.c`. To my surprise (and subsequent confusion), it makes a normal call to `getpid`!

So my question is: How does python determine the result of `os.getpid`? and if such value is indeed obtained by a call to `getpid`, how is that call actually being made?

Comment: `strace -e trace=getpid -f python3 -c 'import os; print(os.getpid())'` showed two calls to the getpid syscall when I tested it.

Comment: @Shawn: Very odd. I just tested strace with the additional `trace=getpid` on two separate systems (both the same version of ubuntu, 16.04, unfortunately). Both print the PID but show no call to `getpid`; only '+++ exited with 0 +++'.

Comment: @Shawn: What system are you using? is vdso enabled?

Comment: Arch and ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: @jww: Perhaps, but from https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v3.19/include/uapi/linux/auxvec.h, it doesn't seem that the system exposes the PID to users as an auxiliary vector value. x86 values don't seem to include the PID either... It also doesn't explain why ubuntu 18.04 makes the call while 16.04 doesn't :/

Comment: Python simply calls the `getpid(2)` libc function. Whatever that does is what Python does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The way the vdso works](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/creating-vdso-colonels-other-chicken) is, among other things, mapping process-specific variables into userspace that the vdso functions know how to read. One of them is the current process ID, so `gettimeofday` doesn't need to make a syscall to access that information.

Now, specifically for `getpid`, it's not actually a VDSO call. In glibc before 2.25, the library would cache calls, and since part of the Python runtime calls `getpid`, there wouldn't be calls to it after the first. From 2.25 onward, the library doesn't cache the process ID, and so every `getpid` call results in a syscall.

Comment: Could you please expand your answer to include why `getpid` reportedly shows up on 18.04 and other systems? Did ptrace gain the ability to trace vdso calls, or does python somehow subvert vdso and makes the call directly?

Comment: Interesting. As it turns out there's a glibc change in 18.04 that removes caching, so every `getpid` call results in a syscall. I've updated the answer. Thanks!

Comment: This raises more questions than it answered (why does my test C program show a `getpid` when straced) but this answer does seem like it's the most likely. I'll investigate further later. Thank you for you for your answer, my unix man!

Comment: I think it's still the PID cache that changed. The C runtime doesn't call `getpid` at all, while Python's does, so a C program will show the first `getpid` call and every subsequent one in all library versions, while Python will only show the first in all versions, and the subsequent calls only in glibc 2.25 and newer. A C program with multiple `getpid` calls might also be interesting, too.